# How to make sure that every time I load Visual Studio from a command prompt for debugging with -debugexe command it loads all the source code?

Tags: visual-studio-debugging

I'm compiling my code via command prompt and often I need to quickly debug something, I launch Visual Studio from cmd with `devenv -debugexe x.exe` but it doesn't load source code which is annoying to do it manually every time I recompile my code. Perhaps there is a setup in Visual Studio to just launch it once and reload all freshly compiled code? Or to attach to a executable once, so I could run it anytime? Attaching to a process every time is annoying as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to make sure that every time I load Visual Studio from a command
>   prompt for debugging with -debugexe command it loads all the source
>   code?

`devenv -debugexe x.exe` is equivalent to debugging the program by **Attach to process**.

**And** `devenv -debugexe x.exe` itself is a quick and easy mechanism to debug the project( **attach to process**), so it doesn't rebuild your project at the same time.
 it does not have the job that loads the source code and build the project before debug it.

[image]

> Perhaps there is a setup in Visual Studio to just launch it once and
>   reload all freshly compiled code? Or to attach to a executable once,
>   so I could run it anytime?

As far as I know, there is no such option to rebuild your project when you attach to process.

**Suggestion**

So to achieve your goal, you should use MSBuild command line to build your project before using `devenv -debugexe x.exe`.

Open [Developer Command Prompt for VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) and then type:

```
cd xxxxx(the folder which the `xxx.sln` exists)
msbuild xxx.sln -t:Build
```

Then you can use `devenv -debugexe x.exe` to debug the program containing the new changes.

**Besdies**, if you want to see the source code and debug on it, you can **Right-click** on the program in **Solution Explorer**-->**Debug**-->**Step into New Instance** and you can debug the source code.

With all of these above, you can get all the new source code on your way.